# running SAS-programs via filename statement - reading order

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to `%include` all SAS-programms located in a folder. My code works, this is what I got:

```
filename x '/mydir/*.sas';
%include x/source2;
```

Additionally, I need the files to be executed in alphabetical order, e.g.

```
01_setup_libraries.sas
02_transfer_data.sas
03_create_tables.sas
```

My tests indicate that this is how `filename` behaves in that context and that I can just use the code above - however, I am unable to find confirmation if this is actually how `filename` works.

Is there any documentation on this, or is there an alternative with comparingly little amount of code? (My best guess was to output the files to a dataset, sort the dataset, then execute record by record).

Comment: It will read the files in alphabetical order on Linux, but filenames are case sensitive. So uppercase letters sort before lowercase letters. On Windows it reads them in alphabetical order based on the uppercase version of the filename.  Since window file names are not case sensitive then it is essentially also alphabetical.

Comment: @Tom exactly the info I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question has been answered in Tom's comment under initial post:

"It will read the files in alphabetical order on Linux, but filenames are case sensitive. So uppercase letters sort before lowercase letters. On Windows it reads them in alphabetical order based on the uppercase version of the filename. Since window file names are not case sensitive then it is essentially also alphabetical." - Tom

Answer (score 3):

Modifying u/Lawrence's solution to use CALL EXECUTE instead which is easier to debug.

```
%let in_directory = .....;

Filename _dir_ "%bquote (&in_directory.)";
data files_available (keep = Filename);
    directory = dopen ( '_dir_' );
    if directory > 0 then do;
        numfiles = dnum(directory);
        do i = 1 to numfiles;
            Filename = dread(directory, i);
            output files_available;
        end;
    end;
    rc = dclose(directory);
run;
Filename _dir_ clear;

proc sort data=files_available;
by filename;
run;

data files_run;
    set files_available;
    str = catt('%include ', quote(filenames), " /source2;");
    call execute(str);
run;
```

Comment: Nice, more elegant

Comment: hi @Reeza, thanks, that is somehow what I came up with as an alternative - since Tom elaborated the "filename"-behavior, I will try to stick with as little code as possible!

Answer (score 2):

I think your best guess is a good idea, output the file names to a dataset, sort and then %include them:

```
%macro get_filenames(in_directory);
    /*  Getting a list of filenames in a directory*/
    Filename _dir_ "%bquote (&in_directory.)";
    data files_available (keep = Filename);
        directory = dopen ( '_dir_' );
        if directory > 0 then do;
            numfiles = dnum(directory);
            do i = 1 to numfiles;
                Filename = dread(directory, i);
                output files_available;
            end;
        end;
        rc = dclose(directory);
    run;
    Filename _dir_ clear;
%mend;
%get_filenames(mydir);

proc sql;
    select
    count(*) 
    ,filename 
    into
     :num_files
    ,:filenames separated by "|"
    from files_available
    order by filename;
quit;

%macro run_programs;
    %do i=1 %to &num_files.;
        %let filename = %scan(%str(&filenames.),&i.,%str(|),m);
        %include "mydir/&filename.";
    %end;
%mend;
%run_programs;
```

Some of this will need a tweak but hopefully it helps.

Comment: CALL EXECUTE on the files_available dataset may be easier?

Comment: Might be an option, not sure if files_available is sorted sufficiently though